# Struggling to evaluate an indefinite integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, approximation, approximate-integration

I tried solving the following integral

$$\int \frac{dx}{(1-\frac{c}x{} ) (\frac{3c}{x}-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}}   $$

How could I incorporate the approximation that x $\approx$ c as I am told that would simplify the integral but still am unable to solve it.

Comment: If $x\approx c$ then the second factor is $\approx 1$. You can take extra terms in the expansion as needed.

Comment: How is the second term approx one?

Comment: Did you even bother to plug in $x=c$? That should've been the first thing you did.

Comment: but the problem is the left hand term vanishes and then the integral is undefined

Comment: That's what makes this an approximation. You don't approximate poles. But you can always approximate continuous functions as points.

Comment: I see thanks for that!! I was never aware of this.

Comment: have you tried integrating it? Try substituting $$u^2=\frac{3c}{x}-1$$